# Install GCC / G++ Version 4.9 in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, gcc, g++

I always like to have the latest version of things, particularly if that thing is gcc, g++ and there has recently been a revision to the c++ standard.

I have forgotten what ppa's I need to add to my system (I think they come from the Ubuntu organization) in order to be able to install g++-4.9.

Please could I be reminded how to complete this process, thanks.

Comment: This helped me in the end but not all the steps worked as I expected http://askubuntu.com/questions/312620/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-8-1-on-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get all the upstream development tools for Ubuntu 14.04 (and its derivatives) from `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

Activate it like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain#PPA_packages

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did this, but `gcc --version` still returns 4.8... (idem `g++ --version`)

Comment: It probably installs as `g++-4.9`. You could set up some symlinks in `~/bin` and add it to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

you may also need to change the symlink "g++" that points to the old library for automated scripts to use the new if that is what you want.
Find the symlink g++ pointing to g++-4.8, it is probably in /usr/bin
Delete it and create a new pointing to version 4.9:

```
sudo ln -s g++-4.9 g++
```